# ExecuteNonQuery() returning positive value but no records inserted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-ce, executenonquery

I have attached a local sqlceserver database(version 3.5.8080.0) with my windows forms application project(vb). When i try to insert the data using the following code,

```
infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(i)
cmd.CommandText = "insert into log(filename,filesize,cdate) values('" & i & "'," &     infoReader.Length & ",'" & Now.ToString(("yyyy-MM-dd")) & "')"
cmd.Connection = cs
cs.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cs.Close()
```

The cs is the sqlceconnection object with following declaration:

```
Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
Dim cs As New SqlCeConnection(String.Format("{0}", strconnection))
```

I have added all the required assemblies and imported the needed namespaces.The cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1 which means there is no problem with the insert command.But when i try to view the data through server explorer, I get no rows inserted. Any help would be highly welcome.

Comment: did you try to refresh the records on the server explorer?

Comment: @JohnWoo yes! I did that and also did the executesql again.

Comment: Are you looking into the development database? or are you using the application database e.g appfolder/debug/Datadirectory Database1.sdf?

Comment: @estebane9 I dont know what stuff are those u named, but I am simply debugging the app from VS 2010. The database I added was using right click on solution explorer project name,Add->New item->Local Database

Comment: Ok, When you use SqlCe the database is a file that is added to your application output folder. You have a DataDirectory in the same folder of your solution. But if you look into the Debug folder you will see the .exe and another DataDirectory. The server explorer is connected to the solution folder, not the Debug folder, that's why you cant see the new row

Comment: @estebane97 would u mind cming 2 chat room?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16803/discussion-between-estebane97-and-rahulserver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, When you use SqlCe the database is a file that is added to your application output folder. You have a DataDirectory in the same folder of your solution. But if you look into the Debug folder you will see the .exe and another DataDirectory. The server explorer is connected to the solution folder, not the Debug folder, that's why you cant see the new row

Comment: Gr8 answer! Works Like a gem! Thanx :D